# Is there any rigorous treatment of Markov Decision Process?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, reference-request, machine-learning, markov-process

I am trying to find a mathematically rigorous introduction to MDP.

There are tons of resouces online but all of them are ... frankly terrible (and not even properly typesetted).

Just picking a few: top three links Google returns for "MDP tutorials"

https://engineering.purdue.edu/~givan/talks/mdp-tutorial.pdf

http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~./awm/tutorials/mdp09.pdf

https://hub.packtpub.com/reinforcement-learning-mdp-markov-decision-process-tutorial/

I don't know why, but they all read something like:

> A MDP is a tuple $(S,A,R,P)$ (sometimes $(S,A,R,P,\pi)$, or
>   $(S,A,R,P,\pi,\gamma)$ or $(S,A,R,P,\pi,\gamma, T)$) where $S$ is a set of states, $A$ is a set of
>   action, $R$ is (depending on who the author is) a determinstic function, a set containing a finite set of values, or a probability distribution over the
>   action and the states, $P$ is a conditional probability or sometimes
>   conditional probability distribution.

In addition, almost all of the references use different notations (various subscripts and superscripts will be added) and have different assumptions and they are all called MDP. I just want one standard reference that eliminates all these ambiguities and conflicting definitions.

Comment: J.R. Norris introduces them briefly with a couple results in their excellent book *Markov Chains* in 5.4. At the end they refer the reader to *Applied Probability Models with Optimization Applications* by S.M. Ross and *Stochastic Models - an algorithmic approach* by H. C. Tijms for “more examples, results and references”.